# Guardar fichero en el escritorio FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy intentando que FPDF me guarde el archivo directamente en el escritorio pero no lo consigo, me lo sigue guardando en la carpeta descargas y me pone como nombre del fichero la ruta. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
$pdf->Output('/C:/Users/Desktop/Fichas/ficha.pdf','D');
```

Comment: Con respecto al nombre, debes hacerlo así: [`$pdf->Output('/C:/Users/Desktop/Fichas/ficha.pdf', 'NOMBRE.pdf','D');`](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm). Con respecto a la ubicación, eso es una configuración del navegador en uso, la cual solo se puede modificar por el usuario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si realizas la la descarga mediante el navegador, quien decide donde guardarlo es el navegador en caso que uses chrome. Cuando realizas la llamada con el parámetro `'D'` lo que indicas es que fuerzas al navegador a realizar la descarga y dado que el nombre incluye una ruta, así es como es nombrado el fichero.

```
$pdf->Output('/C:/Users/Desktop/Fichas/ficha.pdf','D');
```

Es probable que la configuración que buscas es

```
$pdf->Output('F', 'C:/Users/Desktop/Fichas/ficha.pdf');
```

Lo cual guardara posiblemente el fichero en la ruta que quieras, siempre y cuando sea el equipo que ejecuta el servidor.

Nota que el parametro `'F'` va en la primera posición dado que la documentación indica que ese parametro debería ir primero, aunque al hacer el llamado Output el código internamente cambia los parametros para que el primero sea ***I*** o ***D*** o ***F*** o ***S*** y el segundo el nombre del archivo.

Por lo que el valor F  indica guardar el archivo en local(refiriendose al servidor donde se ejecuta).

Comment: Gracias @Hammerfall BK, lo estoy ejecutando con WAMP en Windows en mi ordenador, por lo que quizás si me lo guarde donde quiero. Muchas gracias por la ayuda